# Changes in <td> input texts doesn't reflect in text-area while the Javascript function works fine

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function table_to_text() {
  var j;
  var z = '';
  var k = 4;
  var article1 = new Array();
  for (j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
    article1[j] = document.getElementById("c" + j).value;
    z = z + article1[j];
  }
  document.getElementById("batch_full").innerText = z;
}

function text_to_table() {
  var batch_text = document.getElementById("batch_full").value;
  var length_covered = 0;
  var n = 4;
  var article = new Array();
  var temp;
  var length;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    article[i] = document.getElementById("c" + i);
    length = article[i].getAttribute('maxlength');

    temp = batch_text.substr(length_covered, length);
    article[i].value = temp;

    length_covered = Number(length_covered) + Number(length);
  }
}
```

```css
#batch_full {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: -2.5%;
}

td>input {
  resize: horizontal;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="batch_full" onchange="text_to_table()">Batch input here</textarea>

<table id="results_table" onchange="table_to_text()">
  <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Account Number</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" id="c1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="c2"></td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="c3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" id="c4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="text_to_table()" value="Text to Table">
<input type="button" onclick="table_to_text()" value="Table to Text">
```

When I enter some text in the  element, the changes are reflected in the table  elements, but when I try to edit the text in the  element, the changes are not reflected in the  element.
Please help me in resolving this issue. I'm using Codepen to write this code.

Comment: Please paste the codepen url.

Comment: http://codepen.io/vincent119/pen/vypwgq

Comment: "*When I enter some text in the element, the changes are reflected in the table elements, but when I try to edit the text in the element, the changes are not reflected in the element.*" Not that clear what the steps are.

Comment: Steps I followed.

1) Entered some texts the textarea. Changes got reflected in S.No, Account Number, First Name and Last Name. 

2) Now I make changes in Account Number. The Changes are not reflected in the textarea.

Comment: @epascarello Steps I followed.

1) Entered some texts the textarea. Changes got reflected in S.No, Account Number, First Name and Last Name. 

2) Now I make changes in Account Number. The Changes are not reflected in the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no bugs in your code.For instant reflection of your data which you are entering in either Textarea or Table, replace "onchange" event with "oninput" event in the TextArea and table elements and, Since you are using codepen the "innerText" attribute will not be rendered instead use "value" attribute.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Made the following changes : 

<textarea id="batch_full" **oninput** ="text_to_table()">Batch input here</textarea>
<table id="results_table" **oninput** ="table_to_text()">

function table_to_text() {
..
document.getElementById("batch_full"). **value** = z;
}

Answer (score 0):

Change the `innterText` to `innerHTML`. Seems to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLvqMN

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you see the link ?

Comment: Yes I did. Steps I followed.

1) Entered some texts the textarea. Changes got reflected in S.No, Account Number, First Name and Last Name. 

2) Now I make changes in Account Number. The Changes are not reflected in the textarea.